# What are the rules for handling inequalities?

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality

I just learnt that the inequalities y > 1/x and x > 1/y are not the same. I find this really confusing as in all other (high school) inequalities, we are taught that we can treat inequalities essentially as equalities - we can add, subtract, multiply, divide and log both sides and the inequality still holds (minus some specific cases).
We were told to take test points to determine if the inequality holds in certain regions, but this only addresses the problem on a case by case basis, and doesn't explain the principles behind this.

What are the rules for handling inequalities, and where is the flaw in my current understanding?

The offending inequalities:
[image: The offending inequalities]

Comment: If $a>b$ and $k>0$ then $ka>kb$ but if $a>b$ and $k<0$ then $ka<kb$. So you cannot just multiply or divide

Answer (score 1):

The principle that allows you to add, multiply, etc. both sides of an inequality is that if $b>a$ and $f(x)$ is increasing, then $f(b)>f(a)$. For adding a constant $c$ to both sides ($f(x)=x+c$), this is always true ($b+c>a+c$). Applying exponentiation and logarithms to both sides works likewise, assuming the domain is satisfied, since each of these functions are also increasing. However, with multiplication there's a bit of a hangup.

The function you apply when you multiply both sides by a constant *can be* increasing, but is not necessarily so. Note that $f(x)=ax$ is increasing if and only if $a>0$. To take your inequality from $y>\frac{1}{x}$ to $x>\frac{1}{y}$, you must multiply both sides by $\frac{x}{y}$, that is, apply the function $f(z)=\frac{x}{y}z$. But as we noted before, this function must be increasing to maintain the truth of the inequality, and it's increasing only if $\frac{x}{y}$ is positive.

Thus you have that the inequality is only true when $x$ and $y$ are both positive or both negative.

---

As a side note, with decreasing functions if $b>a$, then $f(b)<f(a)$. That is why you have to flip the sign when you multiply by a negative number or (assuming your domain is entirely positive or entirely negative) take the multiplicative inverse.